# How can I change an object's speed in p5.js if the mouse is pressed in OOP

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Hi guys i'm very new to p5/js and not quite good at OOP programming.

I want to drop a ball by changing its speed once the mouse is clicked.
After trying to write and edit the code many times, the p5 editor didn't  show any error massages but there aren't anything shown up on the display. So, I need a hand and some advices to fix this kind of problem.

Thank you in advance (:

```js
let ball1;
let circleX = 50;
let circleY = 50;
let xspeed = 0; // Speed of the shape
let yspeed = 0; // Speed of the shape

let xdirection = 1; // Left or Right
let ydirection = 1; // Top to Bottom

let rad =50;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  ball1 = new Ball();
  
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  
  ball1.x =20;
  ball1.y = 50;
  ball1.c = color(25,0,100)
  ball1.body();
  ball1.move();
  ball1.bounce();
   
}

class Ball {
  constructor(){
    this.x = width/2;
    this.y = height;
    this.w = 30;
    this.h = 30;
    this.c = color(0,255,0);
    this.xspeed = 0;
    this.yspeed = 0;
  }
  
  body(){
    noStroke();
    fill(this.c);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
  }

   move() {
     
   //this.xpos = width / 2;
  //this.ypos = height / 2;
    this.x = this.x + this.xspeed * this.xdirection;
    this.y = this.y + this.yspeed * this.ydirection;
   }
  
  bounce() {
    if (this.x > width - rad || this.x < rad) {
    this.xdirection *= -1;
  }
    if (this.y > height - rad || this.y < rad) {
    this.ydirection *= -1;
  }
  }
    
  if(mouseIsPressed) { // if the mouse is pressed
        //set the new speed;
  
  this.fill(0, 0, 0);
  this.xspeed =1.5;
  this.yspeed=1.5;
  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some good beginnings to your code. I modified it just a bit to assist toward OOP programming. See the code at the end of my answer for the full source.

---

### Solution

The main question you are asking involves setting the ball's speed when the mouse button is pressed. For that, you should declare a [`mousePressed()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mousePressed) function in your code as such (borrowing from your `if` block):

```js
function mousePressed() {
  // if the mouse is pressed
  // set the new speed;
  ball.xspeed = 1.5;
  ball.yspeed = 1.5;
}
```

That should set the speed of the ball and that should solve your problem.

---

### Other thoughts

Some other steps I took to adjust your code to more working conditions include:

1. I created a `reset()` function to be used in the `setup()` function and potentially able to reset the animation whenever you would like.
2. I changed the `rad` variable declaration to `const rad = 50` since it doesn't change
3. I changed the `Ball` constructor to include initial (x, y) coordinates when creating the ball (could be helpful if creating multiple balls)

   - If you want to create an arbitrary number of balls, create an array and use `array.push(new Ball(x, y))` for each ball and loop through the array to `move()`/`bounce()`/`body()` each ball.
4. I'm assuming `rad` is meant to be the radius of the balls, so I set the `this.w` and `this.h` to `rad * 2` since with and height would equate to the diameter.

```js
let ball;
const rad = 50;
// let circleX = 50;
// let circleY = 50;
//let xspeed = 0; // Speed of the shape
//let yspeed = 0; // Speed of the shape

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  reset();
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  ball.body();
  ball.move();
  ball.bounce();
}

function mousePressed() {
  // if the mouse is pressed
  //set the new speed;
  ball.xspeed = 1.5;
  ball.yspeed = 1.5;
}

function reset() {
  ball = new Ball(width / 2, height / 2);
}

class Ball {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = rad * 2;
    this.h = rad * 2;
    this.c = color(25, 0, 100);
    this.xspeed = 0;
    this.yspeed = 0;
    this.xdirection = 1;
    this.ydirection = 1;
  }

  body() {
    noStroke();
    fill(this.c);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
  }

  move() {
    this.x = this.x + this.xspeed * this.xdirection;
    this.y = this.y + this.yspeed * this.ydirection;
  }

  bounce() {
    if (this.x > width - rad || this.x < rad) {
      this.xdirection *= -1;
    }
    if (this.y > height - rad || this.y < rad) {
      this.ydirection *= -1;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works! I really appreciate your help. Thank you for expanding my knowledge and also your encouragement. (-:

Answer (score 0):

*Numbers before code are line numbers, they might be wrong, but should be close enough...*

- You need to move the `64  if(mouseIsPressed){}` into a function like `47  move()`.
- Also you haven't declared and initialized `39  this.xdirection`
  in the `constructor(){}`.
- I think `67  this.fill(0, 0, 0)` should be `fill(0)`.
- Maybe `24  ball1.body();` should be after the other methods *(24 -> 26 line).*
- I think the `if()` statements in `bounce(){}` are wrong, since they'd need to have `AND` or `&&` instead of `OR` or `||`.

Also you might want to make the `if(mouseIsPressed)` into `function mousePressed(){}` ***mouseIsPressed** is a variable that is true if mouse button is down; **mousePressed** is a function that gets called once when user presses the mouse button.*

```
function mousePressed(){
   ball1.xSpeed = 1.5
   ball1.ySpeed = 1.5
}
```

There might very well be other things i haven't noticed.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I appreciate it. (-: I'll try to revise my toughs and edit the code again. In my opinion OOP is quite complex and I have to practice more and more to master it.